# Show $\sum_{n\leq k\leq 2n}2^{-2k}\log(k)\leq C\, 2^{-2n}\log(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, estimation

I'd like to prove

$$\sum_{n\leq k\leq 2n}2^{-2k}\log(k)\leq C \, 2^{-2n}\log(n),$$

where $C>0$ is a constant. Can someone give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can provide an integral form for such a sum by exploiting Frullani's theorem; partial summation is another way to provide tight bounds. Anyway, it is quite trivial that:
$$\sum_{n\leq k\leq 2n}2^{-2k}\log k \leq \log(2n)\sum_{n\leq k\leq 2n}2^{-2k}\leq \log(2n)\sum_{k\geq n}2^{-2k} = \frac{4}{3}\log(2n) 2^{-2n} $$
that is $\leq \frac{8}{3}\log(n)2^{-2n}$ for any $n\geq 2$.

Comment: What's this Frullani's theorem you're referring to ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: $$-\log k = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-kx}-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx .$$

Comment: BTW, do you know books other than De Bruijn's that cover asymptotics, and especially estimates of sums ?